# what's the meaning of 'quite some' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

I wonder what can be the meaning of **quite some** in this sentence,
a little or much?

your research interests certainly have "**quite some**" overlap with mine.

Comment: It means "much".

Comment: That sentence should either be: _interest ... has_ or _interests ... have_, but not _interest ... have_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [quite some](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/quite-some)
>   A considerable amount of

So there is a considerable amount of research interest that they share.

Comment: What does "considerable" mean?

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/considerable

Comment: **considerable** seems just as non-committal as "quite some".

Comment: And that is why considerable was used to define _quite some_? I don't see your point, sorry.